# Can't resize in iframe

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to resize a div using resize feature in css. In my .css file I have:

```
#test {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

My div is the following:

```
<div id="test">Let the user resize both the height and the width of this div element.</div>
```

It works fine until I put my html in an iframe, there I can't resize the div. What's wrong?

PS: I dont' want to use jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iframe is handled as a new website. To apply your css to your iframe - simply set the reference to you stylesheet, within your iframe.

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.write("<html><head>" +
"<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>" + 
"</head><body><div id='test'></div></body></html>");
</script>
```

By this your iframe will access your stylesheet correclty